# Flutter development environment in elementary OS

Tags: development, vscode

I am a beginner in using elementary OS. I really like the look and feel of the elementary OS and like to setup a development environment in my PC for [flutter](https://flutter.dev/) application development. I googled for which is the best OS elementary OS vs Ubuntu, it's shows me Ubuntu is the suitable OS for development purpose. Is there any flutter developer using elementary OS, please share the experience and difficulties you faced while using elementary OS as development environment. Because i want a stable with light weight and beautiful OS.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you go through the steps on flutter's get started page (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)? All the commands and packages there work great on elementary OS, and I've had no problems with Android Studio (including virtual devices) and IntelliJ IDEA. Also, elementary OS is built on top of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank u for your valuable information. I already read the documentation in the flutter website about flutter SDK installation in Linux. As per your experience, I am choosing the elementary OS as my Linux OS.

Comment: Have fun building great apps! Return here if you encounter any issues.

Comment: Thank u for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am here for share my experience with [elementaryOS](https://elementary.io/). I am installed the elementaryOS Juno version in my PC. Everything works fine. it's really fast and stable. I think it's better than [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) OS for [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) development. Sometimes bluetooth devices is not paired. This is the only problem i am facing in elementary OS.